# Calculating directional derivative on contour plot

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I seem to have a problem in understanding the plot below:

How the example seems to calculate $Δ$$x$ is not clear to me.[image: Question]

Comment: The change $\Delta x$ marked on the diagram is approximately $-0.5$. There is no calculation being performed here. One could equally say $\Delta x\approx -0.4$.

Comment: how is $Δ$$x$ = $-$$0.5$ Is it an assumption?

Comment: $ \Delta x $ is obtained by measuring the length in the plot  and is not obtained by calculation. This measurement gives $\Delta x \approx 0.5$